# Flutter Drawer navigate to a single page multiple times

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

when i pull the drawer and select a page to navigate to it is like create a new instance of that, for example if i clicked on the same page 4 times it shows the animation of opening a new page 4 times and same when i press the back button of the phone.

```
  new ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: new Text("Home"),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(ctxt);
          Navigator.push(
              ctxt, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => MyHomePage()));
        },
```

here's the drawer file i'm using in all the pages

```
class DrawerOnly extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: new Text('Fethi'),
            accountEmail: new Text('Myemail@Mail.com'),
            currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: new NetworkImage('http://i.pravatar.cc/300'),
          ),
        ),
      new ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: new Text("Home"),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              ctxt, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => MyHomePage()));
        },
      ),
      new ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.note),
        title: new Text("ADD Notes"),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              ctxt, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => EditNote()));
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: please show your full code

Comment: it is too long man, that's the part causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the `Navigator.push` to `Navigator.pushReplacement` & remove `Navigator.pop`

It will replace the current screen with the new screen. And it will solve your problem.

To know in detail, just check this documentation:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html

Comment: now when i make changes in home page and go to the second page then go back to home page those changes aren't saved, it is like i opened the page for the first time.

Comment: does it has a relation with the database ?

Comment: Yes, it will replace the current page with the new one which you apply. And it does not have a relation with the database.

Comment: so how can i get back to the old page without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are initializing the `MyHomePage` screen on top of the current screen(starting new screen). In drawer navigation you have to replace the `body:` with the screens you wish to show.

Example :

Take a variable like

```
  int selectionScreen = 0;
```

you can take it as per your need, I took an `int`. Now based on this you can choose which screen you wish to show.

```
new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          // here we display the title corresponding to the fragment
          // you can instead choose to have a static title
          title: new Text("Drawer navigation"),
        ),
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: new Text("Home"),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectionScreen = 0;
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  })
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: _getScreen(selectionScreen));
```

Now you can use `_getScreen()` to get multiple screens, as you add more `ListTile` to drawer list.

```
_getScreen(int selection) {
    switch (selection) {
      case 0:
        return MyHomePage();

      case 1:
        return Screen2();
      default:
    }
  }
```

This will replace the screens in the existing drawer navigation screen.

Please acknowledge if this was the issue you were facing. Thank you.

Comment: yeah i fixed the issue and it is now replacing the pages but when i make changes in home page and go to the second page then go back to home page the changes aren't saved, it is like i opened the page for the first time.